# Elegant way to retrieve nodes by content type?

Tags: nodes, database

Of course I can do something like:

```
$results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE type = '%s'", $content_type);

while ($node = db_fetch_object($results)) {
    // ...
}
```

But is there a more elegant way maybe?

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: @DylanTack The shown query is for Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [node_page_default](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_page_default).
You need just change condition in select query.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module and add a filter on the content type.

Comment: Too much clicking required for such a simple thing :(

Comment: Then you are left with custom coding like you did, and incorporating all the table joins necessary to get all the node information.  In the grand scheme of things, a few seconds of clicking (really only takes a few) will be worth it